# rolling back ddl changes on oracle using flyway

Tags: oracle, flyway

My question: Is there anyway to disable auto-commit of DDL statements in Oracle DB?

Context:
I'm using Flyway 4 to maintain the state of my Oracle DB. As they say in their [faq page](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/faq#rollback), they can't rollback DDL changes in Oracle because DDL is autocommitted in this DB.

For instance, I am moving a column from a table to another table (copying existing values). So I would like to have in the same sql file an ALTER TABLE ADD, then an UPDATE, then an ALTER TABLE DROP. I happened to get an error on the DROP statement but the columns that were added by the first ALTER TABLE remained in place. I would like to be able to rollback that change too.

One work around I am using is adding a separate sql file for each DDL statement. But this is ugly. Any other way of doing this?

Comment: I don't know why someone gave you the downvote, but anyway, Oracle engine works that way. All DDL and DCL are auto committed. Which is a common error in many Oracle scripts, and by accident , commit all their data.

Comment: In your scenario what actions would you like to rollback and under what circumstances?

Comment: I edited the question: if I get an error at ALTER TABLE DROP the new columns remained added. I would like to remove them. If possible, I would like something that is not done in each sql file since there are many files and many colleagues working on this (one might forget to add the statements in his file).

Answer (score 1):

> Any other way of doing this?

As flyway simply runs the migration files you can put anonymous PL SQL blocks in them. With some effort these can then be used to manage errors via PL SQL exceptions to undo all previous steps. If you are manipulating multiple columns each column may need to be in a separate file or all columns would need to be rolled back.

Psuedocode for single column:

```
declare
begin
    -- alter table add new column
    exception when others then
        dbms_output.put_line('Exception adding new column');
        -- nothing to rollback as failed on first step
    end;      

    -- update copy data to new column
    exception when others then
        dbms_output.put_line('Exception when populating new column');
        -- delete any data in new column if committed in blocks
        -- drop new column
    end;      

    -- drop old column
    exception when others then
        dbms_output.put_line('Exception when dropping old column');
        -- ? not sure if you can rollback a failed drop column
        -- delete any data in new column if committed in blocks
        -- drop new column
    end;      

end;
/
```

As you can see this is a bit of effort. You may need to expand your explanation of why you wish to avoid multiple sql files with your colleagues and whether this only affects the database?